# Зависит ли время на создание объекта от количества его свойств и методов?

Tags: c#, .net, производительность

Есть 2 класса:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Prop { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass2
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
    public int Prop3 { get; set; }
    public int Prop4 { get; set; }
    public int Prop5 { get; set; }
}
```

Конструкторы этих классов отработают за одинаковое количество времени или нет?

Comment: [If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses**.](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @Grundy, в данном случае очень много нюансов. Получится множество тестов. Тесты с полями, тесты со свойствами, тесты с методами, ну и различные комбинации этих оптионов. Поэтому я задал вопрос с целью получить теоретический ответ.

Comment: @Grundy, ведь даже проведя все эти опыты, у меня не будет ответа на вопрос "почему так". А это важный вопрос. Я не сторонник подхода "работает - не трогай" :)

Comment: Как минимум, у тебя поменяется вопрос :-)

Comment: Если посмотреть IL генерируемый для данных классов, то можно отметить, что код для конструкторов - **абсолютно** одинаков: в нем просто вызывается конструктор _System.Object_

Comment: @Grundy, а если свойства будут с инициализаторами? `public int Prop1 { get; set; } = 1;`

Comment: Тогда в конструктор добавляется инициализация полей, что, в принципе, логично.

Comment: @Grundy, но все свойства так или иначе получают значение default. Инты вот становятся равными 0. Это не относится к инициализации? Это не отнимает время?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56164/discussion-between-grundy-and-irumba).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Исследования показали, что время выполнения конструктора зависит от количества памяти, выделяемой под экземпляр класса. Соответственно, поля и свойства с неявными get/set (как у вас) влияют, а методы и свойства с явными get/set не влияют (память под них в экземпляре не выделяется).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleTest
{

    public class LittleClass
    {
        public int Prop0 { get; set; } 
    }

    public class BigClass
    {
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }
        public int Prop2 { get; set; }
        public int Prop3 { get; set; }
        public int Prop4 { get; set; }
        public int Prop5 { get; set; }           
    }



    class Program
    {
        const int N = 100000000;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch s;            
            int i; 

            LittleClass lc = new LittleClass();
            BigClass bc = new BigClass();

            /* ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            s = new Stopwatch();            
            Console.WriteLine("BigClass test...");
            s.Start();
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                bc = new BigClass();                
            }
            s.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("t=" + s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
            /* ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            s = new Stopwatch();            
            Console.WriteLine("LittleClass test...");
            s.Start();
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                lc = new LittleClass();                
            }
            s.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("t=" + s.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
            /* ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }  

}
```

**Результат** (оптимизация включена)

[image: Результат]

По моим расчетам, время инициализации класса описывается формулой

t=(2,6*s+43,8)/(10^7) мс

*где s - суммарный размер типов всех членов, под которые память выделяется (см.выше),*

с коэффициентом корелляции 0,99.

Наличие постоянной составляющей, я полагаю, объясняется наличие служебной информации, под которую выделяется, предположительно, 16 байт.

---

Исследование проводилось на машине с процессором с тактовой частотой 2.33 ГГц. Для вычисления времени, не зависимого от машины, надо эту формулу умножить на тактовую частоту, получая время в "тактах процессора":

t = 0,6*s+10,9

Comment: Спасибо за подробности, хотя кое с чем я тут не согласен. В вашей формуле не хватает переменной скорости записи (а может и чтения тоже) памяти. Без этого формула получается заточена именно под вашу конфигурацию. Хотя общая идея ясна и так.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку нет инициализации свойств, IL-код будет одинаков и разницы в скорости работы *скорее всего* не будет.

IL для MyClass2:

```
  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void 
    .ctor() cil managed 
  {
    .maxstack 8

    // [46 9 - 46 26]
    IL_0000: ldarg.0      // this
    IL_0001: call         instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()

    // [49 9 - 49 10]
    IL_0006: ret          
  }
```

IL для MyClass:

```
  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void 
    .ctor() cil managed 
  {
    .maxstack 8

    // [32 9 - 32 25]
    IL_0000: ldarg.0      // this
    IL_0001: call         instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()

    // [35 9 - 35 10]
    IL_0006: ret          

  } // end of method MyClass::.ctor
```

---

Разница все-таки есть, провел тесты с помощью [BenchmarkDotNet](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/HowItWorks.htm). Связано это скорее всего с тем, что для полей автоматических свойств вызывается конструктор по-умолчанию при создании класса. Код программы:

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<ClassCreator>();
        }
    }

    public class ClassCreator
    {
        [Benchmark]
        public MyClass CreateMyClass()
        {
            return new MyClass();
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public MyClass2 CreateMyClass2()
        {
            return new MyClass2();
        }
    }
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Prop { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyClass2
    {
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }
        public int Prop2 { get; set; }
        public int Prop3 { get; set; }
        public int Prop4 { get; set; }
        public int Prop5 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.3.0, OS=Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393
Processor=Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4670 CPU 3.40GHz, ProcessorCount=4
Frequency=3320319 Hz, Resolution=301.1759 ns, Timer=TSC
dotnet cli version=1.0.1
  [Host]     : .NET Core 4.6.25009.03, 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 4.6.25009.03, 64bit RyuJIT


 |         Method |      Mean |    StdDev |
 |--------------- |---------- |---------- |
 |  CreateMyClass | 2.4932 ns | 0.0185 ns |
 | CreateMyClass2 | 3.3029 ns | 0.0982 ns |
```

Comment: Как же нет инициализации свойств? Разве присвоение дефолтного значения (0 для int) не является инициализацией?

Comment: @iRumba, да, так и есть. Добавил тест в ответ.

Comment: Скорее всего, присвоение нулевого значения не видно в IL-коде, потому что оно не осуществляется программой явно. Просто CLR сама обнуляет память перед ее выделением, чтобы обеспечить принципиальную невозможность обработки программой "плохих" данных, независимо от реализации компилятора.